# How to get context

Tags: android, junit

How to get the context of the project which is under test.I have a class which is singleton,To create object for this i need to call one constructor of this class in setUp() method of testcase class,but i need to pass some context as a parameter to call that constructor, but i dont know how to get the context of this testcase class.I got confused whether i shuld pass the context of testcase class or the class which is under test.could any one help in this please.Could any one help me in this

Answer (score 4):

you can get **`getApplicationContext()`** or **`getBaseContext`** or simply **`this`**!

Answer (score 1):

MockContext wouldn't be a good choice, since there are no methods implemented. Every method call will give you an exception.

There is an IsolatedContext which has some stub methods implemented, but still throws a few exceptions.

If your class is extending AndroidTestCase you can simply call getContext() to receive an instance of Context.

Comment: If I recall, this gives you context of test application, not the context of application under test.

Comment: Thats probably true... If you want to test an activity, I'd rather extend from ActivityUnitTestCase<T> where T is your Activity under test. Then you can get the application context using `getActivity().getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 0):

Never used it myself, but the answer is probably here :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html